# Gridstack: Change space between items

Tags: gridstack

Hopefully I'm just missing something simple, but there is a little too much space between the items ("grid-stack-item" divs). I would like a grid where the items are a little closer together. I was hoping maybe someone had a codepen or fiddle that showed how to decrease the space between the items (shrink the columns).

[image]

Relevant code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <!--JQUERY-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNjb53/rY+WmG+4L6tTl9m6PpqknWZvRt0rO1SRnJzw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Bootstrap-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Lodash-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
  <!--Gridstack-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.2.5/gridstack.min.js'></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.2.5/gridstack.min.css" />
  
  <style>
   .grid-stack-item{background-color: #00CED1;}
   .red {border: 1px solid red;}
   .blue {border: 3px solid blue;}
   .red-dash {border: 3px dashed red;}
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grid-stack" style="margin-top: 20px;">
     <div class="grid-stack-item"
      data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0"
      data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1">
       <div class="grid-stack-item-content">BOX 1</div>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-stack-item"
      data-gs-x="2" data-gs-y="0"
      data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1">
       <div class="grid-stack-item-content">BOX 2</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
   var options = {
    cellHeight: 80,
    width: 4
   };
   $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
  });
  </script>
  <!-- Scripts -->
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the data-gs-x attribute of the second grid-stack-item 1 instead of 2 as the width of each grid-stack-item is only 1. At the moment you have a empty space there because you've told it to leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a four years old quetions. But you can change that gap by adding the **margin** parameter to the grid options. Default margin value is 10.I can be an integer (px) or a string (ex: '2em', '20px', '2rem')

```
var options = {
                cellHeight: 80,
                width: 4,
                margin: 5
            };
```

[source document](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/master/doc#marginvalue-numberorstring)